# How do I search for symbols then go to next line in python?

Tags: python

Just starting out in python and getting confused. So i have to create this new program and this is the flowchart I have so far:
Flowchart for program
Open file
(Iterating over lines in a file), for each line in file, If the line starts with the @ symbol, then put the read ID into a variable
Then move to next line (which contains DNA sequence) then get length
Write the read ID, then length to an outfile (file of a different name)
At the very end, after last line then close the outfile.

SO far, all I've done is open my text file. Now, how would I make it so that each time a new line starts with an @ symbol, I put the read ID into a variable then move to the next line?

```
@D00780:143:CAJ3WANXX:1:1105:2036:1975 1:N:0:CTTGTA
ATTTGNTGTATGTGCTTGGCTGAGGAGCCAATGGGGCGAAGCTACCATCTGTGGGATTATGACTGAACGCCTCTAAGTCAGAATCCCGCCCAGGCGGAACGATACGGCAGCGCCGCGG
+
CCCCC#@=FGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG0EGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGDGGGGGGG
@D00780:143:CAJ3WANXX:1:1105:2106:1978 1:N:0:CTTGTA
ATCTANTTCAAATTCCTCCCTGTACGAAAGGACAAGAGAAATAAGGCCTACTTCACAAAGCGCCTTCCCCCGTAATTGATATCATCTCAACTTAGTATTATACCC
+
CCCCC#@EFGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
@D00780:143:CAJ3WANXX:1:1105:2469:1982 1:N:0:CTTGTA
GGGCANGGCGAAGCCAGAGGAAACTCTGGTGGAGGTCCGTAGCGGTCCTGACGTGCAAATCGGTCGTCCGACCTGGGTATAGGGGCGAAAGACTAATCGAACCATC
```

here is part of my txt file. the read IDs come after the @ symbols and need to be put into variables. How do I make the program recognize each @ symbol, put each read IDs into different variables then move to the next line and get length of that line?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide the data example to make question more clear

Comment: Can you please show us an extract of the file you are parsing?

Comment: You really should present your code, not a verbal description of a flowchart. That said, how about `if line.startswith("@"):`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Banananana have you had a look at the answers? Has any solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd find which lines start with @ and save the read IDs -

```py
read_ids = list()
with open(path, "r") as f:
    for i in f.readlines():
        if i.startswith("@"):
            read_ids.append(i[1:])
```

That, if I understood correctly and the read ID is all of the line that comes after the @.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you can create an algorithm in pseudo code then you can translate it into Python code.

**Algorithm**

```
Initialise a list to store the data
Open the text file
Read the file content line by line until the end of the file
If the line read starts with '@':
  Append the ID and the length of the next line to the list
```

**Python code**

```
data = list()
with open(file_path) as file_handle:
    while True:
        read_line = file_handle.readline()
        if not read_line:
            break
        if read_line.startswith('@'):
            data.append((read_line[1:].strip(), len(file_handle.readline().strip())))
```

**Explanation**

The `while True` condition creates an infinite loop.

The `if not read_line` condition evaluates to True when the end of the file is reached so the program will have to `break` out of the infinite loop when this condition is met.

The `.strip()` method is required because in Python the `.readline()` method appends the newline character to the line of text read from the file.

The `data` variable is a list of Tuples of the following format: `(ID, <length of string>)`

```
[('D00780:143:CAJ3WANXX:1:1105:2036:1975 1:N:0:CTTGTA', 118),
 ('D00780:143:CAJ3WANXX:1:1105:2106:1978 1:N:0:CTTGTA', 105),
 ('D00780:143:CAJ3WANXX:1:1105:2469:1982 1:N:0:CTTGTA', 106)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Context: this is a [fastq file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format), which contains DNA sequencing information together with quality score.

There are two approached to solve this problem: manually and using BioPython.

### Manually

You can use a simple list/dictionary comprehension and `re.split`. The idea is to split first the groups (starting with `\n@` or `\n+\n`, while keeping `@`), select the `@` groups and split again the identified/sequence.

NB. I assumed the whole content of the file is loaded in the variable `text` (which you can do using `f.read()`)

##### as list of tuples

```
import re
out = [(x[0][1:], len(x[1]))
       for s in re.split(r'(?:\n(?=@))|\n\+\n', text)
       if s.startswith('@') for x in [s.split('\n')]]
```

output:

```
[('D00780:143:CAJ3WANXX:1:1105:2036:1975 1:N:0:CTTGTA', 118),
 ('D00780:143:CAJ3WANXX:1:1105:2106:1978 1:N:0:CTTGTA', 105),
 ('D00780:143:CAJ3WANXX:1:1105:2469:1982 1:N:0:CTTGTA', 106)]
```

##### as dictionary

```
import re
out = {x[0][1:]: len(x[1])
       for s in re.split(r'(?:\n(?=@))|\n\+\n', text)
       if s.startswith('@') for x in [s.split('\n')]}
```

output:

```
{'D00780:143:CAJ3WANXX:1:1105:2036:1975 1:N:0:CTTGTA': 118,
 'D00780:143:CAJ3WANXX:1:1105:2106:1978 1:N:0:CTTGTA': 105,
 'D00780:143:CAJ3WANXX:1:1105:2469:1982 1:N:0:CTTGTA': 106}
```

### Using specialized tools (BioPython)

```
from Bio import SeqIO

## as dictionary
out = {r.id: len(r.seq) for r in SeqIO.parse(filename, 'fastq')}

## as list of tuples
out = [(r.id, len(r.seq)) for r in SeqIO.parse(filename, 'fastq')]
```

output (dictionary):

```
{'D00780:143:CAJ3WANXX:1:1105:2036:1975': 118,
 'D00780:143:CAJ3WANXX:1:1105:2106:1978': 105,
 'D00780:143:CAJ3WANXX:1:1105:2469:1982': 106}
```